# Rewrite below incorrect statement in two ways using isnull and coalesce

Tags: mysql

Rewrite below incorrect statement in two ways using `isnull` and `coalesce`:

```
[select * from Test_Table where Test_ID=null]
```

How shall I procede? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`Null` isn't a valus, you want to get `NULL` You need to use `IS NULL`

```
select * 
from Test_Table 
where Test_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` can not be used with `NULL` values

You need to use `IS NULL`  or use the NULL-safe equal to operator `<=>`

> The <=> operator is equivalent to the standard SQL IS NOT DISTINCT
>   FROM operator.

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

**IS NULL example**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 test_table 
WHERE
 Test_ID IS NULL
```

**<=> example**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 test_table 
WHERE
 Test_ID <=> NULL
```